# Install MySQL on Ubuntu Natty without password prompt and using shell variable as password

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, debconf

I'm trying to install MySQL on Ubuntu Natty from a shell script. However, I keep running into one major issue: when I try to define the password outside of the shell script.

Below is the code to my shell script (which I have saved in /etc/init.d/install_mysql:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password $dbpass | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password $dbpass | debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

So what I enter in the terminal is:

```
dbpass="mysqlpass"
chmod +x /etc/init.d/install_mysql
/etc/init.d/install_mysql
```

MySQL installs, but it installs without a password, so I can just do something like `mysql -uroot` to access mysql (which I don't want).

The funny thing is if I put the password in the shell script as regular text, it works ok. So if I my install script is as follows, everything works (i.e. I must specify a password to access mysql):

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password mysqlpass | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password mysqlpass | debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

Is there a way I can use a shell script variable to define my password in the shell script, instead of entering the password literally?!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I just edited the variable declaration `$dbpass="mysqlpass"` to `dbpass="mysqlpass"`. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $dbpass="mysqlpass"
> ```

Yeah, this is several types of wrong. Variable names don't start with `$`, and variables won't be passed to the environment of subprocesses unless exported.

```
dbpass="mysqlpass"
export dbpass
```

Note that environment variables are *not* considered a secure mechanism for sharing data; you may want to retool your script to read the password from stdin instead, which would be a bit more secure.

Comment: It was a typo, my apologies. I'm trying the suggestion you mentioned about using export, I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It turns out `export dbpass` was just what I was looking for. It works like a charm now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbpass="mysqlpass"
```

should be

```
dbpass="mysqlpass"
```

As you've written it, $dbpass will be evaluated, and isn't defined, so comes out as an empty variable, boiling down to

```
="mysqlpass"
```

---

well, since it was a typo, then here's the answer:

MySQL looks for the envvar `MYSQL_PWD`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/environment-variables.html

Comment: It was a typo, sorry about that.